# NodeJS/Express using Bootstrap for UI elements/interaction

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, bootstrap-5

I have an .html file and a corresponding .js file (using Bootstrap) I need to deploy this to Heroku.

I'm really trying to avoid having to rework this entire project, I need more than just bootstrap styling. This project pulls data through an API, and populates based on the data pulled. Input is also needed from user to update the backend through API...

I've tried to find examples of how to accomplish just pulling in html/js into nodeJS/expressJS... but it seems most examples are just to use Bootstrap.css for styling, or there's no actual UI interaction coded in the example.

Any links or input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a html file prepared in the server side. You need a view engine like ejs or pug. You can pass data into the html page. Another way of doing the same thing is a framework called NextJs or NuxtJs but you need to know React or Vue.

You can add bootstrap.css into the public folder and `express.static` will handle the problem. Or you can use CDN links too.

Then you can add the url of bootstrap.css into the html head.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html